# Change ICollectionView source in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionview

My question is related to that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093579/changing-collectionviewsource-source-in-a-mvvm-world), but I create a new post as the question is very old.

I am beginning to use `ICollectionView`, so I made the ViewModel as the following :

```
public ICollectionView SampleListView { get; set; }
SampleListView = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = SampleList }.View;
```

The problem is when I change the source, I used to do the following :

```
List<T> list= GetMyList();
SampleList=new ObservableCollection<T>(list);
```

The accepted answer (by blindmeis) explains that there are two options to solve that issue :

1) *Instead of replacing the ObservableCollection you can use .Clear() and add the items from the new Collection. This has the additional bonus of not breaking your grouping and sorting.*

2) *whenever you replace your ObservableCollection you have to create a new ICollectionView for sorting and grouping.

```
this._view = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.MyCollection);
```

You can simply bind to your collection if you take the DefaultView

`<DataGrid Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />`

My question is, what is the best way to do that? I mean the "clean" solution?

For me the faster would be to use solution two(only because I have a big project with lot of ListViews, and would be a big work to take option 1).
What are the advantages of taking the option 1? Is it worth it?(except keeping grouping/sorting).

Comment: What "issue" are you trying to solve? If you want to replace the entire collection for whatever reason, why don't you?

Comment: Just learned recently about ICollectionView(easier to apply some filters, sort...), so I am trying to apply them on my project, and I got in the same situation as the person who made that old post. 2nd solution seemed much easier to apply, but finally I decided to use 1st solution that seems more correct way? In fact I believed this would be very long to change everything, but it was faster than expected, will finish tomorrow I guess.